# How to define nginx root when using a custom runtime in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, nginx, yaml

I'm using Google App Engine Flex and need to use a custom runtime so I can install some thirdparty libs. I need to define the document_root to be 'public', only the runtime_configs seems to get ignored when using a custom runtime, so this isn't working:

```
runtime_config:
   document_root: public
```

I've also tried adding in a nginx-app.conf file with the root declared (I'm also unsure how to get the app path, so i've just hardcoded it):

```
root "/app/public";
```

But I get the error:

> nginx: [emerg] "root" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-app.conf:1

I haven't been able to find the answer to this in the docs, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this [Hello World example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-custom-runtimes-samples/tree/master/nginx), you can see that root folder is declared in the nginx configuration file in your case `nginx-app.conf`

First of all you have to properly configure your `Docker` file, which will create public folder and copy all the files from local machine to it:

```
FROM nginx

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/public/

# Copy static files from local public folder
ADD public/ /usr/share/nginx/public/
RUN chmod -R a+r /usr/share/nginx/public
```

Than you have to define a path to that public folder in `nginx-app.conf` file:

```
http {
    server {
        root /usr/share/nginx/public;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was after! Although it seems you can't use nginx-app.conf because this will just appended to the default nginx.conf (which what was causing my issues). So you're right in that I need to make a whole new nginx.conf and copy this across via Docker script.

Comment: @BenSouthall I tried replacing the nginx.conf file with no luck, still didn't take the root as I defined it, was there anything additional you had to do to get it to work?